# Difference between a power strip, a power distribution unit (PDU) and a remote power switch?

Tags: power-supply-unit, power-distribution-unit

I would like to know what is the main differences between a [power strip](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=power%20strip), a [power distribution unit](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=power%20distribution%20unit) (PDU) and a [remote power switch](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp#q=remote+power+switch).

Thank you.

Comment: did you research what any of these are before asking...

Comment: Yes, but they seem quite the same. I wanted a precise definition for each of them because they seem to be often confused on hardware websites! Should I delete the post?

Answer (score 2):

Power Distribution Unit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_distribution_unit

Power Strip: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_strip

A power strip adds outlets. A Power distribution unit distributes higher voltage and current into lower current and voltage (EG a 30amp 220v feed into two 15amp 110v feeds). A remote power switch allows power cycling generally via a network connection.

Much like modern modems, routers, switches a single unit may contain features of all three.

Comment: I think your final sentence is the best part of the answer.

Comment: The term "PDU" is often also used for Rack mounted power strips ([some companies prefer the term **CDU**, as do I](http://www.servertech.com/support/technical_library/cdu_vs_pdu/)). "Rack PDUs" (CDUs) usually don't modify voltage - they're basically glorified power strips, usually with monitoring (current draw, often environmental monitoring capability for temperature/humidity reporting), and sometimes with remote power switching capability.